# How to send Parameter/Query in HubConnection SignalR Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1, signalr-hub

I'm trying to send parameters into connection to `signalr`

```
Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("https://familyapp.azurewebsites.net/StoreHub?token=123")
                .Build();

            await Connection.StartAsync();
```

In my server side i take this parameter from HttpContext:

```
 public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var group = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["token"];

            string value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.ToString()) ? group.ToString() : "default";

            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, value);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();              
        }
```

but `GetHttpContext ().Request.Query["token"]` is null, because the group name receives "default" as indicated by the following code

```
string value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.ToString()) ? group.ToString() : "default";
```

am I forgetting a step?
I am using aspnetcore 2.1

Answer (score 4):

From your code , I think that you use ASP.NET Core SignalR .NET client library .Here is a working demo using .net client in console app based on your code.

*Console app*

1.Install the client library `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` with version 3.1.3 from **Manage NuGet Package**

2.connect to hub

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://localhost:5000/chatHub?token=123")
            .Build();

await connection.StartAsync();
```

*SignalR hub side*

You could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to setup your SignalR hub.

1.Setup SignalR routes

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
 {
    routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
 });
```

2.Hub class:

```
public class ChatHub:Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var group = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["token"];

        string value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.ToString()) ? group.ToString() : "default";

        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, value);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}
```

Here is my [demo link](https://github.com/SherryCXL/SignalRDemo) , you could refer to.