# How can I make one to one chat system in Asp.Net.Core Mvc Signalr?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I want to implement private chat system with Mssql Database. This codes works as public when I send the message, message is appears all clients. But I want to one to one chat system. One user enter the receiver id which stored in database and message text, then send the message to Receiver . Then the message appears in receiver message area which has that receiver id.

Here is my js code

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chathub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + ":" + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});
```

Here is my hub class

```
using MentorShip.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MentorShip.Hubs
{
    public class SignalRChat:Hub
    {
        Context c = new Context();
        
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
           
            await  Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage",user,message);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my html code

```
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="connectionId"></div>
                <div class="col-2">Receiver Id</div>
                <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="userInput" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">Message</div>
                <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="messageInput" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <ul id="messagesList"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send the message to specific user, you could use the following methods:

1. **Use Single-user groups**.

   You can create a group for each user, and then send a message to that group when you want to reach only that user. The name of each group is the name of the user. If a user has more than one connection, each connection id is added to the user's group.

   For example, base on the [getting start document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), I have create a SignalR application, it will send message to all users. Then, in the ChatHub class, add the Authorize attribute and override the OnConnectedAsync() method, in the OnConnectedAsync method, we could create a group based on the Identity User. Then, add a SendMessageToGroup method to send message to group.

   ```
    [Authorize]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {  
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        { 
            Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public Task SendMessageToGroup(string sender, string receiver, string message)
        {
            return Clients.Group(receiver).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", sender, message);
        }  
    }
   ```

   In the Index.cshtml page, add a Receiver input element to enter the receiver name (the same as the group name).

   ```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">Sender</div>
            <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="senderInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">Receiver</div>
            <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="receiverInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">Message</div>
            <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="messageInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   ```

   Then, update the sendButton click event in the chat.js file:

   ```
    document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        var sender = document.getElementById("senderInput").value;
        var receiver = document.getElementById("receiverInput").value;
        var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;

        if (receiver !="") {

            connection.invoke("SendMessageToGroup", sender, receiver, message).catch(function (err) {
                return console.error(err.toString());
            });
        }
        else { 
            connection.invoke("SendMessage", sender, message).catch(function (err) {
                return console.error(err.toString());
            });
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
   ```

   After that, we could send message to specific user, screenshot as below (if the receiver is null, it will send message to all user, else, will send message to specific user):

   [image]
2. **Send message via the ConnectionID.**

   From the above sample code, in the OnConnectedAsyc method, we could get the ConnectId and the User Name, then, you could store them in the database. Then, you can add the SendMessageToUser method in the ChatHub.cs. In this method, you could query the database and find the connectionId based on the receiver name, after that using `Clients.Client("connectionId").SendAsync()` method to send the message to a specific user.

   ```
    public Task SendMessageToUser(string sender, string receiver, string message)
    {
        //based on the receiver name to query the database and get the connection id

        return Clients.Client("connectionId").SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", sender, message);
    }
   ```

Here are some related articles, you can refer to them:

[Use hubs in SignalR for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

**Update**:

Detail Steps:

1. Open the Visual Studio 2019 (the latest version), and create an Asp.net Core Web Application (named SignalRApp, using .net core 3.1 version):

   Choose the MVC template and change the Authentication  to "Individual User Accounts".

   [image]
2. Using the following command in the Package Manager Console tools. More detail information, check [EF Core Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs).

   `add-migration InitialCreate`
   `update-database`
3. After that, we could run the application and register users. The login screenshot as below:

   [image]
4. Add the SignalR client library

   - In Solution Explorer, right-click the project, and select **Add** > **Client-Side Library**.
   - In the **Add Client-Side Library** dialog, for Provider select **unpkg**.
   - For Library, enter **@microsoft/signalr@latest**.
   - Select Choose specific files, expand the dist/browser folder, and select signalr.js and signalr.min.js.
   - Set Target Location to wwwroot/js/signalr/, and select Install.
     LibMan creates a wwwroot/js/signalr folder and copies the selected files to it.
5. Create a SignalR hub.

   In the Project folder, create a Hubs folder and add a ChatHub.cs file with the following code:

   ```
    namespace SignalRApp.Hubs
    {
        //require using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
        //require using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
        [Authorize]
        public class ChatHub : Hub
        {
            public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
            {
                Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
                return base.OnConnectedAsync();
            }
            public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
            {
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
            }

            public Task SendMessageToGroup(string sender, string receiver, string message)
            {
                return Clients.Group(receiver).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", sender, message);
            }
        }
    }
   ```
6. Configure SignalR in the Startup.cs file. You could check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-signalr).

   The startup.cs file as below:

   ```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddSignalR(); 
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
            });
        }
    }
   ```
7. Add SignalR client code:

   **[Note]** In this step, please pay attention to the js file path. If the js file doesn't load successfully, the client code will not work.

   In the Home controller Index page(Index.cshtml), replace the content as below:

   ```
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    }

    <h1>Index</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">Sender</div>
            <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="senderInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">Receiver</div>
            <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="receiverInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">Message</div>
            <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="messageInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <ul id="messagesList"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
   ```

   In the wwwroot/js folder, create a chat.js file with the following code:

   ```
    "use strict";

    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

    //Disable send button until connection is established
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
        var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
        var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = encodedMsg;
        document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    });

    connection.start().then(function () {
        document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

    document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        var sender = document.getElementById("senderInput").value;
        var receiver = document.getElementById("receiverInput").value;
        var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;

        if (receiver != "") {

            connection.invoke("SendMessageToGroup", sender, receiver, message).catch(function (err) {
                return console.error(err.toString());
            });
        }
        else {
            connection.invoke("SendMessage", sender, message).catch(function (err) {
                return console.error(err.toString());
            });
        }


        event.preventDefault();
    });
   ```

After that we could send messages to user via groups. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you send me Use Single-user groups codes as zip file?

Comment: Hi @CanCumaYaman, Sorry, we are not allowed to share the code sample via zip files, because of our policy. But, I have already posted the related code about the Single-User Group method. You can reproduce it using the following steps, 1, Create a new Asp.net core MVC application (remember to [select the "Individual User Accounts" Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miEZ3.png)), 2. According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to add SignalR, 3. Use the code in the above reply to send messages.

Comment: In my sample, I'm using Asp.net Core identity, and use user name as the group name, you could set a break point to debug your code and check the group name, make sure using correct name. If you have any problem when reproduce the problem, please let me know freely.

Comment: I already have a project asp.net core 2.1 mvc but I did not use Asp.net Core Identity and did not select individual user account. I want to send message specific user which stored my database you told me in the above solution with Send message via the ConnectionID I tried and I did, but now I can send mesage to specific user use connection id but this id changes every refresh or another browser not constant I dont want to use connection id I wanna use email adress or User constant id which stored in db id but I cant implement this to my project how can I fill that method to I want.

Comment: `I dont want to use connection id I wanna use email address or User constant id which stored in db id but I cant implement this to my project` As we all known, in the SignalR application, to send messages, we have to build the connection to the user first, then, send a message, so the connection id will refresh every time. From your description, the user was stored in the database, you could use the Single-user groups method, use the email address as the group name, then send message to the group(note: still need to build a connection, then the user could receive the messages).

Comment: I tried all options but still cant do this please send me your Use Single-user groups codes as a zip file to my email adress.

Comment: I don't have much time to deliver the project please send me your rar file

Comment: Hi @CanCumaYaman, I quite understand your feeling now, but as I said in my previous, for security reason, we are not allowed to share the code sample via zip file or using our personal email. I have also told my manager about your scenario, it is just a simple sample, but still not allowed. I will update my reply and tell you the details steps that I did, you can try it, if meet any problem, please let me know freely.

Comment: Hi @CanCumaYaman, I have updated the reply, please check the details steps. When I create a sample based on the detail steps, I think perhaps the issue is related to the SignalR js path and the chat.js file path. since they are not load success, it will cause the code doesn't work. you could use F12 developer tools to check it. Besides, you can also create a new asp.net core web application and follow the above detail steps.

Comment: Hi @Zhi thank you very much your support. I implemented according to your updated steps and I achieved in Asp.net Core 3.1. but I hava an exsisting project and this project in asp.net core 2.1 also I did not select indivudual user account option when starting the project. So Context.User.Identity.Name code in your hub class does not work in my code. I want to use this instead of Context.User.Identity.Name, after the user login in the system and select send message to another user he can use receiever email adress which stored in database instead of Context.User.Identity.Name. How can I do this

Comment: can you have an idea about this?

Comment: Hi @CanCumaYaman, you could try to send the username via query string, check this link: [send Parameter/Query in HubConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232651/how-to-send-parameter-query-in-hubconnection-signalr-core-2-1). Since this thread is too long, if you have any further questions, I suggest you could try to create a new thread, so that other community member will join us and help you solve the problem.

Comment: okey thank you very much for your all supports