# Back-end for Location sharing between two clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, location

Want to create one back-end for location sharing between clients and back-end should be in .net-core and MS-SQL.
Simple approach is **user1** send x and y co-ordinates and save to db every 2 second and **user2** call the get api and get the x and y co-ordinates in every 2 second.

**Issue** - If 1 million user register then 1 million request per 2 sec will hit. Not good for servers and MS-SQL

**Question** - Is it possible to create web socket for every user which send their location and send the data to that socket in every 2 sec and when other user who want to see the location, merge that user with socket.

or any other approach???

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use memory based database (Redis for example) to store the data (save and answer).
2. Web socket as transport, but even using web sockets you need to store the data somethere. To store in the application - not a good idea.
3. Maybe you can use SignalR - receive data from one client and send it to all connected clients. But there will be some difficulties with many connections.

Comment: Hi Valeriy, suppose U1 send co-ordinates every sec to server and other client will get that co-ordinate at runtime, how redis will help in this?
i guess in web-socket, no need to store data.

Comment: In the case you described - no need of storing.

Comment: But remember - by default, SignalR retains 1000 messages in memory per hub per connection.

Comment: And there is no any info about the backend - web backend or raw sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Asp.net SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0), it can send messages to all connected clients simultaneously. For example, a chat room. Or, send messages to specific clients or groups of clients.

The SignalR Hubs API provides the following method to send messages to clients:

- **SendMessage** sends a message to all connected clients, using Clients.All.
- **SendMessageToCaller** sends a message back to the caller, using Clients.Caller.
- **SendMessageToGroups** sends a message to all clients in the SignalR Users group.

  ```
    public Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    public Task SendMessageToCaller(string user, string message)
    {
        return Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    public Task SendMessageToGroup(string user, string message)
    {
        return Clients.Group("SignalR Users").SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
  ```

More details information about using it, check the following links:

[Tutorial: Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

[How can I make one to one chat system in Asp.Net.Core Mvc Signalr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568240/how-can-i-make-one-to-one-chat-system-in-asp-net-core-mvc-signalr/65577044#65577044).

[Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

Comment: Hi Zhi Lv, one quick question in Asp.net SignalR, suppose i create one url www.test.com/signalR then all register client can send the data over this url to servr in every 2 sec. Is it possible ??

Comment: Yes. Asp.net SignalR provide high-frequency messaging functionality.

Comment: Ok, @zhi-lv, I'll try that. thanks for suggestion.