# SignalR mapping User Id to Connection Id from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am building an ASP.NET Core application with Angular, and I am trying to implement a basic, one-on-one chat functionality using SignalR.

Since I want to allow one-on-one chatting and make chat messages persistent at some point, I'd like to be able to map User Id to SignalR Connection Id and send messages directly to a user based on their Id.

Now, all the examples I've seen use code within a Hub, which makes sense since Hub keeps track of Clients and their connection ids. But other logic that I'll have starts and ends inside my Controller, of course, and I can't call a hub directly from a controller.

Since SignalR is supposed to be relying on Identity by default, his is what I've tried so far:

```
[Route("send")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendRequest([FromBody] Chat.Models.Message message)
    {
        var userId = Guid.Parse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)); // I'd like to register this (current) userId with SignalR connection Id somehow
        
        var sender = new ChatSender { Id= userId, Name = user.FullName };

        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", sender, message.MessageText); // can't extend this, nor access hub directly

        //var recipient = _hubContext.Clients.User(message.To); // message.To is a Guid of a recepient
        //await recipient.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", sender, message.MessageText);
        return Ok();
    }
```

The code above works as a broadcast, but if I replace the `_hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync` with two commented out lines below, it does nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> SignalR mapping User Id to Connection Id

To map the user id /name with the connection id, you need to use the Hub's [OnConnectedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.hub.onconnectedasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method to get the userid/username and the connection id, then insert them into database. Code like below:

```
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public ChatHub(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        //get the connection id
        var connectionid = Context.ConnectionId;
        //get the username or userid
        var username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        var userId = Guid.Parse(Context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));

        //insert or updatde them into database.
        var CId = _context.UserIdToCId.Find(userId);
        CId.ConnectionId = connectionid;
        _context.Update(CId);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

> map User Id to SignalR Connection Id and send messages directly to a
> user based on their Id.

You can pass your receiver id or name from your client to the `SendRequest` method, according to the receiver id or name to find the signalr connection id from database. After find the receiver's connection id, then use the following code to send message:

```
await _hubContext.Clients.Client("{receiver connection id}").SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
```

the more code you can refer to:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubContext;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public HomeController( IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {               
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            _context = context;
        }
         ...
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="receiver">receiver id or name</param>
        /// <param name="message">message </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("send")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendRequest([FromBody] string receiver, Message message)
        {
            //1. according to the receiver id or name to find the signalr connection id
                //To map the user id /name with the connection id, you need to use the Hub's OnConnectedAsync method to get the userid/username and the connection id.
                //then insert them into database
            //2. After find the receiver's connection id, then use the following code to send message.
            await _hubContext.Clients.Client("{receiver connection id}").SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
             
            return Ok();
        }
```

**Note** When the receiver is disconnected,remember to delete the receiver's connection id from database, avoid sending error.

Besides, you can refer to [How can I make one to one chat system in Asp.Net.Core Mvc Signalr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568240/how-can-i-make-one-to-one-chat-system-in-asp-net-core-mvc-signalr/65577044#65577044) to know more.